# quickManager for modx revolution - front end editor without front end logining

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

In modx evo was plugin to edit content from front end, without logining at front end like in "front page" for revo.
Have revo posibility to do this with only back end logining?

Answer (score 0):

Bob Ray released a tool for adding/editing resources via the front-end called [News Publisher](http://modx.com/extras/package/newspublisher) that does what you're asking.

There's also [Site Editor](http://SiteEditor) that does what you're asking. It never moved beyond the alpha release stage.

Comment: I see `NpEditThisButton`.  I need redirect to back end(`manager/?a=resource/update&id=605`).
I can do this with a link and current id, but how hidden it from others?